# KendoUI typescript binding for ASP.NET MVC5 not compiling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, typescript

Anyone used the KendoUI Typescript bindings with an ASP.NET MVC5 application?

I dropped the bindings into my project and when I attempt to compile, Visual Studio reports 13000 errors.  I wonder if this is an incompatibility between my TypeScript version and what Kendo depends on but cannot find any prerequisites in their [doc](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/mvc-report-viewer-extension-embedding.html).

Some of these errors include:

```
C:\dev\quantra\src\AipsWebClient\AipsWebClient\kendo\typescript\kendo.all.d.ts(273,30): error TS2186: Type name 'Class' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for 'kendo.Class'.
1>  
1>C:\dev\quantra\src\AipsWebClient\AipsWebClient\kendo\typescript\kendo.all.d.ts(298,24): error TS2186: Type name 'Observable' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for 'kendo.Observable'.
1>  
1>C:\dev\quantra\src\AipsWebClient\AipsWebClient\kendo\typescript\kendo.all.d.ts(311,33): error TS2186: Type name 'Observable' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for 'kendo.Observable'.
1>  
1>C:\dev\quantra\src\AipsWebClient\AipsWebClient\kendo\typescript\kendo.all.d.ts(315,26): error TS2186: Type name 'View' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for 'kendo.View'.
1>  
1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are hitting this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/171
I often replicate it wrongly including the class definitions twice...